# Creating new function returns it empty in Javascript and Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have simple knockout viewmodel:

```
function HumanViewModel(humanViewModel) {
  if (humanViewModel=== undefined || humanViewModel=== null) {
    humanViewModel= {};
  }

  var self = this;

  var Id = humanViewModel.Id || '';
  var Name = humanViewModel.Name || '';
}
```

I'm fetching some json data from a server, to fill this model, here is what's going on success:

```
 var result = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < receivedData.length; i++) {
        var vm = new HumanViewModel({ Id: receivedData[i].Id, Name: receivedData[i].Name });
        result.push(vm);
      }
      self.Humans.push.apply(self.Humans, result);
```

The problem is here: `var vm = new HumanViewModel({ Id: receivedData[i].Id, Name: receivedData[i].Name });`. Variable `vm` contains `HumanViewModel`, but this viewmodel doesn't contain `Id` and `Name`, it simply contains nothing;

However, when I'm looking at debugger, inside `HumanViewModel` everything works fine, but in the end, `vm` contains nothing.

I have no idea, where data have been lost. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing the ID and name in a variable, you should save it on the function context.

The following code should work:

```
function HumanViewModel(humanViewModel) {
  if (humanViewModel=== undefined || humanViewModel=== null) {
    humanViewModel= {};
  }

  var self = this;

  this.Id = humanViewModel.Id || '';
  this.Name = humanViewModel.Name || '';
}
```

Whenever you call `new HumanViewModel`, you will get a HumanViewModel wish the id and name because you set them using `this`, which refers to the HumanViewModel in this scope.

Answer (score 1):

When you define `var self = this`you have immediate access to a value of `this` that refers to the instance being created.

`self` is being used to make sure the original `this` value is maintained within the object. For example if you have a computed observable it  can be bound to the appropriate value of `this`. So once you assign this to `self` within your object you can use `self.Id = ...`.

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/135/

```
var data = [{ Id: 1, Name: "Name 1" },{ Id: 2, Name: "Name 2" },{ Id: 3, Name: "Name 3" } ];

function MainViewModel(){
   var self = this;
   self.Humans = ko.observableArray([]);

   //on success
     self.Humans($.map(data, function (item) {
    return new HumanViewModel(item);
  }));
}

function HumanViewModel(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
  self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
}

var viewModel = new MainViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```